# Do Spring Qualifier annotations get passed down dependency chain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having trouble trying to leverage AutoWired while using multiple implementations

Suppose I have the class structure below. How could I use autowired to somehow was the qualifier down to the AnimalProcessor class to then select which Fetcher I want. There is no need for a Factory here as this would be static.

Thanks,

I know I could potentially solve this with generics but suppose the needs are similar. I'm also aware that perhaps this means my class structure is improper - I don't believe it is as this would be fairly simple with dagger2.

```
CatController {

@Qualifier("Cat") @NonNull private final AnimalProcessor processor;

}
```

```
DogController {

@Qualifier("Dog") @NonNull private final AnimalProcessor processor;

}
```

AnimalProcessor implements Processor {
@NonNull private final Fetcher fetcher;

public void doSomething() {
}

}

public class CatFetcher implements Fetcher {
}

public class DogFetcher implements Fetcher {
}

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `@Qualifier` works. If you use `@Qualifier` when you autowire the `AnimalProcessor`, then Spring expects that there are two separate Spring beans of type `AnimalProcessor` with the names `"Cat"` and `"Dog"`. But you have only one `AnimalProcessor` and you expect it to somehow know if it has been called by class `CatController` or class `DogController`. You should setup your app context with two instances of `AnimalController`, each with the appropriate `Fetcher`.

Comment: I'm aware that manually creating the instances is an option as a bean. What I was hoping was that I could apply a Qualifier to nested properties. The benefit is that I could use AutoWired rather than needing to manually instantiate everything as a bean.

Comment: Spring does not support applying qualifiers to nested properties in that way.